# Tensorflow Warning - Could not load dynamic library 'cupti64_101.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_101.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've seen other similar issues related to cupti dll error.  However, the answer seems to be that the dll location needs to be in the path.  Well, my dll is in the path.  The warning listed in the title is followed by several errors related to the fact that the cupti dll was not loaded.

```
(venv) PS D:\Projects\tensorboard> $env:path -split ";" 
D:\Projects\tensorboard\venv/Scripts 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp 
C:\Windows\system32 C:\Windows C:\Windows\System32\Wbem 
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ 
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ 
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\libx64 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\include 
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.4.0\ 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\ C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\ 
C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps 
(venv) PS D:\Projects\tensorboard>
```

[image: CUDA Extras folder]

```
Configuration:
Windows 10 Pro Version 1909
Python 3.7.7
Tensorflow 2.2.0
Tensorboard 2.2.1
cuda toolkit 10.1
```

Here is a snapshot of a couple of the warning/error messages.  Several more followed these.

```
2020-05-10 00:48:37.426822: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cupti64_101.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_101.dll not found
2020-05-10 00:48:37.432568: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1408] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
```

Comment: I see `lib64` in your actual path showing the picture of directory contents, and `libx64` in the PATH given in your path variable: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\libx64`

Comment: That was it!  I totally glossed over that.  I fixed it and now it works.  Thanks a million.  I suspect that the mismatch may have occurred since I had installed multiple versions of CUDA over the past few months.  Thanks again.  Perhaps you can submit your answer below and get credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

There is no `cupti64_101.dll` file presented at `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\libx64`.

Due to this `Could not load dynamic library 'cupti64_101.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_101.dll not found` warning has appeared when ever trying to run Tensorflow.

Once `cupti64_101.dll` copied to the above location, issue has resolved.

Comment: Added dll to libx64, but now receive further error messages: Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES and ActivityRegisterCallbacks( AllocCuptiActivityBuffer, FreeCuptiActivityBuffer)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES and EnableCallback( 0 , subscriber_, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_DRIVER_API, cbid)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED    Can you advise please?

Comment: see [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM-permission-issue-performance-counters)

Comment: Note to myself the next time I find this answer: Restart Visual Studio for path changes to apply