# nvprof command error: cupti64_102.dll was not found

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nvcc, nvprof

When I try to run `nvprof` command in Command Prompt, System Erros pops up and says "The code execution cannot proceed because cupti64_102.dll was not found. Reinstall the program may fix this problem."

I have installed the CUDA Toolkit 10.2 but `cupti64_102.dll` is not in `/bin`.

System: Windows 10, Quadro K4200, CUDA10.2, CUDA Toolkit 10.2

Comment: it won't be in `/bin`.  You have to locate where it is and add it to your PATH variable.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707730/tensorflow-warning-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cupti64-101-dll-dlerror).  You have to add something like `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\extras\CUPTI\lib64 ` to your PATH.

Comment: This solved the issue. I added a PATH to extras and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @ Robert Crovella is right.

Comment: [this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM-permission-issue-performance-counters) may also be of interest, after the PATH issue is fixed.

Answer (score 10):

Just go to Environment Variables select path

Add the following string to your path

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\extras\CUPTI\lib64

then `nvprof` will work as intended.

Comment: You really wonder how a multi-billion $ company that earns most of it's income with CUDA use is not able to create an installer that adds the proper path for the included binaries.  Given that's a multi-year spanning bug, no one appears to care.