# CUDA nvprof on Windows: "Warning: unable to locate profiling library, GPU profiling skipped" (NOT cupti64_102.dll)

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, nvprof

I am trying to use nvprof on a cuda/c++ program, but I get the output:

```
======== Warning: unable to locate profiling library, GPU profiling skipped
... my output ...
======== Warning: No CUDA application was profiled, exiting
```

My command:

```
nvprof.exe -o prof.nvvp ./debug/my.exe args
```

It's a pascal GPU, drivers are up to date, I can run CUDA programmes without issue. I have CUDA 9.0, 10.1 and 11.0 installed. Path and CUDA_PATH link to 11.0. I have not found any answers to this question online.

There are some similar questions to bad installations, but only [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pgprof-unable-to-locate-cuda-driver-library/135644) with the same warning. Found nothing for windows.

I suspect some kind of bad installation, but I have reinstalled the CUDA Toolkit multiple times already and the examples from the [install guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html) run fine.

What should I try next? My goal is to find inefficiencies in my program for optimization (serialization, memory usage, occupancy etc.). nprof seems to be the best/only option for this.

The error is NOT the same as [nvprof command error: cupti64_102.dll was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865257/nvprof-command-error-cupti64-102-dll-was-not-found). This error (and it's solution) is the " similar error" I mentioned. I already have the path to cupti in PATH.