# Could not load dynamic library 'cupti64_101.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_101.dll not found

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pycharm, tensorflow2.0

Have some problems with Nvidia Cuda, installed v10.1 with tensorflow 2.2.0, but have warning with 'cupti64_101.dll.

```
2020-05-18 22:26:25.054229: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cupti64_101.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_101.dll not found
2020-05-18 22:26:25.054229: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1408] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
2020-05-18 22:26:25.054412: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1447] function cupti_interface_->ActivityRegisterCallbacks( AllocCuptiActivityBuffer, FreeCuptiActivityBuffer)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
2020-05-18 22:26:25.054619: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1430] function cupti_interface_->EnableCallback( 0 , subscriber_, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_DRIVER_API, cbid)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
```

PATH is also ok:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64
```

[File of course installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvzdn.png)

Comment: depending on how you installed TF, the PATH has to be updated in your virtual environment as well.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707730/tensorflow-warning-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cupti64-101-dll-dlerror).

Comment: @RobertCrovella, i've installed it with `pip install`

Comment: Then you will likely need to update the PATH in your python virtual environment.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can update the PATH of my Virtual Environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated PATH in virtual environment and now it works)